# What font is the big text of these shots?

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I'm looking for the font used for [*Design Better*](https://dribbble.com/shots/4580686) and [*The Tropics*](https://dribbble.com/shots/4458412) on the images below I saw on Dribbble (I don't have a Dribbble account so I can't contact the designers).

I've searched on Font Squirrel [font identifier](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator) and on [WhatTheFont](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) but without any success.

Can anyone help me please?

[image: Design Better]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the font  thanks to [WhatFontIs](https://www.whatfontis.com/), it's called *Oraqle Script* and can be downloaded [here](https://www.pixelsurplus.com/freebies/oraqle).